# Create a Spotify playlist using spotipy

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to create a playlist using the spotipy library. I followed the instructions on their website alongside this solved question [Spotipy invalid username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46879418/spotipy-invalid-username) . When running the code provided in this question (fitted to my Spotify developer account) everything works fine. However when trying another scope corresponding to my object of creating a playlist I get the same username error as mentioned in the linked question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\d92167\Spotify\Create_Favorites.py", line 23, in <module>
    sp.user_playlist_create(cred.user_name, name=playlist_name)

  File "C:\Users\d92167\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 784, in user_playlist_create
    return self._post("users/%s/playlists" % (user,), payload=data)

  File "C:\Users\d92167\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 302, in _post
    return self._internal_call("POST", url, payload, kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\d92167\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 267, in _internal_call
    raise SpotifyException(

SpotifyException: https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/*My Username*/playlists:
 Invalid username
```

My code:

```
import spotipy
import cred 

scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
token = spotipy.util.prompt_for_user_token(cred.user_name,scope,client_id=cred.client_id,client_secret=cred.client_secret,redirect_uri=cred.redirect_url) 
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)


playlist_name = 'Test'  
sp.user_playlist_create(cred.user_name, name=playlist_name)
```

I am using Python 3.8 and Spotipy version 2.20.0

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 2 possible solutions:
1: You forgot to type user=

```
sp.user_playlist_create(user=cred.user_name, name=playlist_name)
```

2: Maybe the user_name in the cred file is wrong. You can get the username with this code:

```
sp_user = sp.current_user()
user_name = sp_user['uri'].split(":")[2]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Solution 2 worked for me. Since my Spotify account is connected to my Facebook account the displayed username did not match the correct one.